# Is there a way to programmatically trigger a VueJS element with .native using $refs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have searched GitHub Issues and Google but I can't seem to find the solution that fits my needs.

#### Template:

```
<v-file-input
    dense
    accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif"
    @change="onImageChangeHandler"
    v-show="false"
    ref="fileInput"
></v-file-input>
<v-btn
    dense
    color="primary"
    @click="onUploadClickHandler"
    small
>
    <v-icon left>mdi-camera</v-icon>
    Upload Photo
</v-btn>
```

#### JS:

```
onImageChangeHandler(e) {
    if (e) {
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.readAsDataURL(e);
        fr.addEventListener("load", () => {
            this.localPersonalData.image = fr.result.split(
                "base64,"
            )[1];
        });
    }
},
onUploadClickHandler(e) {
    this.$refs.fileInput.$el.click(); // I need to click the hidden file input
}
```

Upon closer inspection, I found out that Vuetify parses v-file-input component in nested divs and the input element is at the bottom of the html tree.

```
<div
  data-v-a2f0f47e=""
  class="v-input v-input--dense theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted v-file-input"
  style="display: none;"
>
  <div class="v-input__prepend-outer">
    <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend">
      <i
        role="button"
        class="v-icon notranslate v-icon--link mdi mdi-paperclip theme--light"
      ></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="v-input__control">
    <div class="v-input__slot">
      <div class="v-text-field__slot">
        <div class="v-file-input__text"></div>
        <!-- I want to click this input -->
        <input
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif"
          id="input-333"
          type="file"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="v-input__append-inner">
        <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--">
          <i
            role="button"
            class="v-icon notranslate v-icon--link material-icons theme--light"
          ></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="v-text-field__details">
      <div class="v-messages theme--light">
        <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Therefore, I probably need to use .native but how do I do that programmatically?

EDIT: Should I just use native html input with type file instead?

Comment: ping me on skype syed_haroon, let's figure it out. Be sure you have fast internet to share your screen.

Comment: @Syed Unfortunately, I cannot do that at the moment because I am at work.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to open a file right?
Try this

```
<input type="file" ref="file" style="display: none">
<v-button @click="$refs.file.click()">Button to open the file</v-button>
```

And with the ref in js use as **this.$ref.file** and get your file you uploded
To clear the reference **this.$ref.value=""**

Comment: Yeah. But I am looking for a way to programmatically use .native